# Prove that a group of order 3 must be cyclic.

Tags: group-theory

Is my argument correct, if not what is wrong with it. 
If the group $G$ is not cyclic, this means that there is not element of order 3. 
So if $G=\{e, a, b\}$ then $|a|=2$ and $|b|=2$, a contradiction because by Lagrange's Theorem element order divide group order but 2 does not divide 3. Hence $G$ is cyclic.

I just want to show if this is correct or not and why, I do not need a proof.

Comment: Yep, correct as written.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks.

Comment: @Reader, have you had Cauchy's Theorem?: the order of an element must divide the order of the group. So if the group has order 3, then there must be an element of order 3 and hence powers of this element fill the whole group.

Comment: @ Nicky Hekster Thanks.

Comment: You do not need Lagrange's theorem to do the problem. Just the cancellation law is enough.

Comment: @Pantelis Damianou But the easiest argument is by using Lagrange. Am I right?

Comment: The most elementary method is to use Sudoku! The products $ab$ and $ba$ must be equal to $e$ (using cancellation law). By default $a^2=b$. Therefore $a^3=a^2 a =ba=e$.

Comment: @Pantelis Damianou Thanks