# Number of finite groups of a given prime order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

How many possible group of order 3 are there?  I can only think of one such group.

Comment: Only one group of any prime order, because the order of a nonidentity element is a nontrivial divisor of the group's order.

Comment: @JohnMa I would say not exactly; the first answer on that question implicitly assumes Lagrange's theorem, and the writer admits that in the comments. Presumably the asker here hasn't yet seen/proven Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: Right, I guess if you didn't know already you should check that the cosets of a subgroup partition the group and all have the same size.

Comment: Try writing down the table of a group with elements $e$ (neutral element), $a$ and $b$. As you go step by step, you'll find that the group axioms force your hand, and there is only one way to fill the table. The $e$ column and row are easy. Then show that $ab$ can't possibly be $a$ or $b$. Continue that way for $ba$, $aa$ and $bb$. Remember that each element must appear exactly once in each row and in each column.

Comment: Related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228868/prove-that-a-group-of-order-3-must-be-cyclic

Comment: My algebra professor used to call the groups of prime order "simple simple", because they have no (nontrivial) proper subgroups. If anyone feels that a solution of the earlier Question can be or should be given without explicitly relying on Lagrange's Thm., it could be added there.

Comment: Jaynot, I think yours is a different question from the ones that have been described as duplicates. If you edit your question to say why those don't answer the question for you (e.g., they refer to "Lagrange's Theorem" and the definition of "cyclic" groups), then you can request that this question be reopened.